# Template varargs and explicit instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, constexpr

I am trying to use a couple of new C++11 features together.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


// Trying out template varargs.
template<typename T, T... args>
struct Test
{
    // Using constexpr
    // I had assumed that with this I did not need to
    // explicitly create an object `values`
    // that the compiler will work this out at compile time.
    static constexpr T              values[] = {args...};
};

// Explicitly instantiate
// the template to force it to generate the appropriate code. 
template struct Test<int, 1, 2, 3>;


typedef Test<int, 1, 2, 3>  TestInt;

int main()
{
    // Silly test to see if it worked.
    std::cout << TestInt::values[0] << "\n";
}
```

This results in a linker failure.

```
> g++ -std=c++11 tp.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Test<int, 1, 2, 3>::values", referenced from:
      _main in tp-f3440e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have tried a couple of variations of explicitly defining the `values` array. But none have compiled successfully.

Any help appreciated.

#### Update:

Apparently this compiles for @Nikos Athanasiou with his example here
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/474fd3183db003f1

So is this a known compiler bug?

```
> g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: `typedef` doesn't cause explicit instantiation.

Comment: Note `values` is still not defined. As long as a static member initialized in the class definition is not ODR-used, it should be ok.

Comment: @chris: Yes. That's my problem how do I define it.

Comment: @LokiAstari, Without testing, `template<typename T, T... args> constexpr T Test<T, args...>::values[] = {args...};`

Comment: It doesn't fail [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/474fd3183db003f1)

Comment: @chris: Already tried that. Note because it is `constexpr` it has to be defined in at the point of declaration. So you can **not** also do it outside the class.

Comment: @LokiAstari, Sorry, it would seem I fail. Removing the outside initializer instead of the inside one then maybe.

Comment: @chris: Nope. Fails to compile with `template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression`

Comment: Possibly related: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10714

Comment: @LokiAstari, [Really, interesting](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f625a6f998fe44a).

Comment: @T.C.: Does look related. But it uses `const` rather than `constexpr`. It notes it is fixed but neglects to mention what version it was fixed in.

Comment: @LokiAstari, But it does mention the rejection of out of line definitions with incomplete array types, which seems to be the issue. I'm guessing a workaround that will work for you is specifying the size via `sizeof...(args)`.

Comment: @chris. Your linked example compiles for me. Put it in an answer I will accept.

Comment: @LokiAstari, Oh, excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`values` is not defined just by the initialization, but the initialization needs to be kept inside `Test` because of `constexpr`:

```
template<typename T, T... args> 
constexpr T Test<T, args...>::values[];
```

See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a95b7d4740cf6fd4) for a full sample that works in GCC 4.9 as well as Clang 3.4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


// Trying out template varargs.
template<typename T, T... args>
struct Test
{
    // Using constexpr
    // I had assumed that with this I did not need to
    // explicitly create an object `values`
    // that the compiler will work this out at compile time.
    static constexpr T values[] = {args...};
};

template<typename T, T... args> 
constexpr T Test<T, args...>::values[];

// Explicitly instantiate
// the template to force it to generate the appropriate code. 
template struct Test<int, 1, 2, 3>;


typedef Test<int, 1, 2, 3>  TestInt;

int main()
{
    // Silly test to see if it worked.
    std::cout << TestInt::values[0] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I was sure I had tried that. Its one of those times were I wish that I had every version I tried in some form of source control so I can go back and compare every try I made to the final answer to find the subtle mistake I made. But thanks.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I know the feeling.